# How to use attributes based on condition. (disable by a flag)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, custom-attributes

I'm using the "Authorize" 
from: `System.Web.Http`

attribute at base controller.

the issue is that i need to use it based on condition.

(say i have a mode i don't need authentication/authorization).

how i can achieve it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way to do this is to override the `AuthorizeAttribute`, and add you custom logic inside it.
Here we have two cases in case you want to use it with `MVC` controller override the `AuthorizeCore()` method and use `System.Web.Mvc` name space, like the following:

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        bool isExceptionalCase = GetIfExceptional();//Assuming here where you look for some other condition other than user is authorized
        if (!isExceptionalCase && !authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Second case and it is in your case you will be using it with WebApi controller you can override `IsAuthorized()` instead and use `System.Web.Http` namespace:

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        bool isExceptionalCase = GetIfExceptional();//Assuming here where you look for some other condition other than user is authorized
        if (!isExceptionalCase && !authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use the custom attribute on an action or controller instead of using the standard one:

```
[MyCustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi - did u mean to override protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)?

Comment: `override bool AuthorizeCore`  didn't work for you ? @user10776203

Comment: i'm looking @ System.Web.Http version 5.2.3.0 and don't see such method

Comment: @user10776203 check updated answer, hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AllowAnonymousAttribute in the specific method or controller to "override" the AuthorizeAttribute used inside your base controller.

Check the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835113(v%3dvs.118)

As an another option you can create a custom attribute and use it inside your base controller. In this way you can add all the logic that you need to take decisions inside the custom attribute.

Check the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes

Regards, LA.